# create an auto-incrementing result column in oracle

Tags: sql

I'm trying to produce the following results:
`emp_no, book_no, book_id`
Where `emp_no` and `book_id` are the actual columns on the table, but `book_no` is a value that is incremental, for example:

```
emp_no,book_no,book_id
1234,01,AB33
1234,02,GF44
5678,01,HH78
5678,02,EE98
5678,03,JJ03
```

Is it possible to do this in a standard query without defining variables beforehand (like in sqlplus), and if so please could you give me an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  emp_no,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY emp_no ORDER BY book_id) AS book_no,
        book_id
FROM    books
```

Comment: That works, thanks! It also lead me to find other useful Analytical functions here: http://www.orafaq.com/node/55